# How to get only incoming edges on mySQL graph?

Tags: mysql, graph

I have a Graph represented on a mySQL table as:

```
uidFrom, uidTo
   1       4
   4       1
   1       5
   5       1
   6       1  <- only incoming edge
```

How to get only the "6, 1" pair, having only "1" as input? I mean, how to query the only incoming edges to node "1" (not both incoming and outgoing like 4 or 5)?

Thanks in advance;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT uidFrom, uidTo
FROM Graph g
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Graph rev WHERE rev.uidFrom=g.uidTo AND rev.uidTo=g.uidFrom
)
```

Here is a [demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a655f/1).

Comment: @vicmota1 Performance depends on your indexes: if you have an index on `(uidFrom, uidTo)` or two separate indexes on `uidFrom` and `uidTo`, you should do fine.